# Mysql INSERT INTO...SELECT.... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

I have this `insert into select duplicate key update` query but after executing it twice, the amount of rows get doubled. Stack overflow wants me to add text, so I'm just writing stuff at this moment because I dont think you guys need more explanation as this query is quite self explanatory.

EDIT 1: For clarification: it should not get doubled, I want the data to get updated.

EDIT 2: Table Info

```
CREATE TABLE `Distance` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `distanceType_myId` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   `common_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `distance` double NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=786421 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

EDIT 3: Updated table info

```
CREATE TABLE `Distance` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `distanceType_myId` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   `common_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `distance` double NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `uniqueId` (`distanceType_myId`,`common_id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=786421 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Actual Query:

```
INSERT INTO Distance (common_id, distance, distanceType_myId)
SELECT 
c.id, 
AVG(
  ROUND(
    (
      6371 * acos(
        cos(
          radians(p.lat)
        ) * cos(
          radians(a.lat)
        ) * cos(
          radians(a.lng) - radians(p.lng)
        ) + sin(
          radians(p.lat)
        ) * sin(
          radians(a.lat)
        )
      )
    )* 1000
  )
) AS distance, 
'culturel' AS distanceType 
FROM 
immobilier_ad_blank AS c 
LEFT JOIN Adresse AS a ON c.adresse_id = a.id 
JOIN POI AS p on p.discr = 'Culturel' 
AND p.lat IS NOT NULL 
AND p.lng IS NOT NULL 
AND p.lat != '' 
AND p.lng != '' 
AND p.lat != 'Latitude' 
AND p.lng != 'Longitude' 
WHERE 
ROUND(
  (
    6371 * acos(
      cos(
        radians(p.lat)
      ) * cos(
        radians(a.lat)
      ) * cos(
        radians(a.lng) - radians(p.lng)
      ) + sin(
        radians(p.lat)
      ) * sin(
        radians(a.lat)
      )
    )
  )* 1000
)< 5000 
AND a.lat IS NOT NULL 
AND a.lng IS NOT NULL 
AND a.lat != '' 
AND a.lng != '' 
AND a.lat != 'Latitude' 
AND a.lng != 'Longitude' 
GROUP BY 
c.id 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE 
common_id = VALUES(common_id),
distanceType_myId = VALUES(distanceType_myId)
```

Comment: we need the `show create table Distance` output, else we are flying blind on the UNIQUE index necessary to make it happen

Comment: `on duplicate key` triggers when the primary key clashes. If you're getting duplicate fields, clearly the PK isn't the same in them.

Comment: @twentylemon Ya, the primary keys are not the same actually but I dont really care about them, I just want them to get updated base on the 2 variables I have put in the duplicate statement

Comment: i can be wrong, but let's say `fred` is not a PK but has a unique key on it. that would trigger the update. so it doesnt need to be the PK, which is often never passed for autoincs. I mean you would almost never update the PK

Comment: Okay, your primary is auto-increment, so that's not going to trigger an ON DUPLICATE.  I would say that your common_id sounds like the next most likely one to put a UNIQUE index on, but I see you are updating it in your ON DK UPDATE.  So, when WHAT is the same do you want to have it update the existing entry instead of create a new one.  Whatever that WHAT is needs to be a UNIQUE constraint whether it's a single or multiple columns.

Comment: well I think the OP knows now it doesn't work that way. mysql can't read your mind and figure out the clash

Comment: well thanks guys, I never specificed actual indexes while using doctrine...

Comment: Ugg Doctrine ... sorry.  I shouldn't gripe I use it an it's ok, it has issues for me with in-memory data verses inserted data errors.  But, I have some complex relationships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, you don't have a unique key. In your table you need a unique identifier or a natural key as opposed to a surrogate one ( primary key ).

Primary keys have no relation to the data, they are surrogate keys.  For example you cant look at a row and know that the primary key for it is one without having the primary key.

A natural key is like a name in a database of only names, or a phone number in a database of phone numbers, it could be a state in a database of states. You wouldn't have two entries for Michigan, or Ohio, for example they are unique by their own right.

Surrogate keys are nice for relationships or use as foreign keys because they are not related to the data.  A bad example would be if suddenly the US decided to add a letter to the state's abbreviation. You would have to update all your relationships.  In other words you could change the state record and not have to change any other data in your database, because the surrogate key is not related to the data. ( a better example would be making North and South Michigan )

So each has there own use and reason for being.

***UPDATE***

```
INSERT INTO
    Distance (common_id, distance, distanceType_myId)
    VALUES ( 1,20.0,'culturel' ) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    id = LAST_INSERT_ID( id ),
    common_id = VALUES( common_id ),
    distance = VALUES( distance ),
    distanceType_myId = VALUES( distanceType_myId )
```

This is how I did it in the past reading some old code, then it updates the insert id as well.

**UPDATE1.1**
However, all that said I have found in my testing that if you use PDO with exceptions you can improve insert performance by just ignoring the error. That is if you don't actually want to update the row, or need the id.  For example if you just are inserting and don't want duplicates.( code for example only not tested )

```
 try{
     $PDO->query( "INSERT INTO
    Distance (common_id, distance, distanceType_myId)
    VALUES ( 1,20.0,'culturel' )" );
 }catch( PDOException $e){
     if($e->getCode() != 24000 ){ //not 100% sure of the code number
        //rethrow if not duplicate key
        throw new PDOException( $e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $e );
     }
 }
```

Comment: @DrewPierce - thanks, I had a good database teacher back in College

Comment: Last question, how do I point to this index in the query if the actual index column doesn't exist ? (updated the question with the updated table info)

Comment: What do you mean point? how do you return the PK or how do you make a unique key?  You cant use the PK as a unique key because it doesn't exist before making the row, hence your issue.

Comment: Well, after updating the table with an index `KEY uniqueId ('distanceType_myId','common_id')'`  what should I write here `ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE unique_id=unique_id` ? Even after adding the index and executing the code twice, the rows still get doubled.

Comment: Did you dump the data from the database before adding the new unique key.  Because you cant add the unique key if there is duplicate data already.

Comment: @delmalki - sure did you see my last bit, about PDO and exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a unique index - since the only unique key in your table is the auto incrementing `id` field, you'll need to add a `UNIQUE` constraint that will be triggered by your `INSERT` statement.